# Why is SD-WAN a more suitable option than MPLS for cloud?

Tags: mpls, wan

I keep coming across the statement that because of the growth in cloud computing, SD-WAN is a more suitable option than MPLS for connecting remote sites.

Can anyone give me an explanation why?

Comment: Marketing people say lots of things.  Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: @RonTrunk I understand what you mean but objectively what does SD-WAN provide that MPLS doesn't?

Comment: Maybe faster provisioning?

Comment: You can’t really compare them. MPLS is a routing/switching technology while SD WAN is more of a management and provisioning tool.